# Reload TableView from applicationWillEnterForeground

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

i try to reload a tableview when the app enter in foreground.
in the ViewController -> viewDidLoad:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(updateTableViewData:) name: @"UpdateTableViewAccueil" object:nil];
```

in the ViewController the method used:

```
-(void)updateTableViewData:(NSNotification *) notification
{
[self readMsgsFromDB];
[self reloadTableMsgsReceived];
}
```

in appDelegate.m -> applicationWillEnterForeground

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: @"UpdateTableViewAccueil" object: nil];
```

after i launch the app from xcode, the first time when app enter in foreground the table is reloaded, but not the next times

Do you have some advices? Thanks in advance

Comment: your implementation design looks suspect. Is `readMsgsFromDB` synchronous? If so, the main (UI) thread will block while data is loaded. A better approach would be load data in the background whenever desired (app entering foreground is fine) and have the UI refresh triggered on the main thread when the background data update is complete.

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar issue while trying to reloadData on receiving an NSNotification. It seems the notification is received in a thread different from the main thread. The below code, helped fix it.

**Swift:**

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {self.tableView.reloadData()})
```

Replace 
     self.tableView.reloadData()
  with the code you are using to reload the tableview.

Comment: you could leave it where it is and just call the tableView reload on the main thread using dispatch async. The code in swift would be:  Replace self.reloadTableMsgsReceived() with dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {self.reloadTableMsgsReceived()})

Answer (score 0):

On a side note, you do not have to post a custom notification to capture the fact that the application will enter the foreground.  Try swapping this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(updateTableViewData:) name: @"UpdateTableViewAccueil" object:nil];
```

With this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateTableViewData) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
```

If that works, you can remove the post notification you have.

Comment: same results, the table reload just the first time